# Uploading file and display its name as a post

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file and replace its name with the title name, but I am unable to get the file name by echo in controller even not in as a `POST` in profiler.

I also need to rename it but before that I need to know the post value ie file name.

Here I am posting my code.

My view

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('emailtemplate/do_upload');?>

<tr class='odd gradeX'>
    <td class='center'>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
    </td>
    <td class='center'>
        <input placeholder='Title For Your File' name='title' class='form-control'>
    <td class='center'>
        <input placeholder='Comment On File' name='comment' class='form-control'>
    </td>
</tr>

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

My Controller

```
function do_upload()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['encrypt_name']     = true;
    //$file=$this->input->post('userfile');
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->data();
    $file_name = $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
    echo $file_name;


    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('add/addfile', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('add/addfile', $data);
    }
    $this->output->enable_profiler(true);
}
```

Comment: In codeIgniter access post values by `$this->input->post();` same as $_POST

Comment: how to rename the uploaded file??

Answer (score 0):

To rename uploaded file with POST value:

```
//get extension 
  $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfile"]['name']));
  $config['file_name'] = $this->input->post("title").'.'.$ext;
```

Remove `$config['encrypt_name']     = true;`. Otherwise your file name will be encrypted .

Make sure that your `title` doesn't not exist in your uploaded folder. Or append some random number / characters with title.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function to upload the file :-

it takes argument i.e field_name

```
    public function fileUpload($field) {
    //get file extension
    $exts = @split("[/\\.]", $_Files[$field][name]);
    $n = count($exts) - 1;
    $ext = $exts[$n];
    //create image name  or replace it with your desired name
    $imageName = date("Ymdhis") . time() . rand();
    $config['file_name'] = $imageName; //set the desired file name
    $config['overwrite'] = true;        
    $config['allowed_types'] = str_replace(',', "|", $ext);
    $config['upload_path'] = ABSOLUTEPATH . 'product/original/';
    $config['optional'] = true;
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width'] = '00';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field, true)) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $r = $error;
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $r = "sucess";
    }        
    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the bellow i have written code it can be helpful you

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/path';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|jpg|jpeg|gif';
        $config['max_size']    = '1000000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1000000';
        $config['max_height']  = '1000000000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $files = $_FILES;

        if(isset($files['file']['name']))
        {   
            $filename = $files['file']['name'];
            $ext = end(explode(".", $filename));
            $_FILES['file']['name']=  date('d').date('m').date('y').'_'.date(time()).'.'.$ext; //here i am changing file name with current date as your wish to change your logic   

        //  print_r($_FILES);exit; check the changed name

           if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) 
             {
              $upload = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
              $imagename = $upload['upload_data']['file_name']; //uploaded your image name
             }
             else
             {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    print_r($error); //error 
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:Hey user3345331 , See the line

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

Replace With this

```
$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
```

This userfile is the ID of Input box with filetype in your HTML code.